# Project Managment in GitHub - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, git, github, project-management

I am working as a part of a team which is responsible for building a server side (nodejs) for a system that has a website (html 5 + js) and mobile application (cordova).

Server's code placed at github and each time we make a commit, all the data are pushed to the server (heroku).

Currently, we (server side team) are working in a single branch (development) with a single server, and due to this, we have lots of conflicts each time one of us commits his code. Another problem we have, even though we debug our code locally before committing it, sometimes we forget or need to change something small (for example: website team demands us to change variable name we send them) we must make new commit. So, after week of work we have 100 commits.

We have tried to fork the project but that slows the project development.

Could someone please refer me the source which explains how should we manage our project?

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you need to compartmentalise your development design so not all developers working on the same scripts. Be it a module, class or a component.

[React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) for an  example really helps in the case of break down web user interface development to a component. Each engineer should be working on  different component as much as possible , so you only conflict during integration which very minimal as developer working on his own component.